# Extracting a subdirectory of repository A to a different repository B using mercurial

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I want to move a part, i.e. one subdirectory of an existing, private mercurial repository to a new, public repository on bitbucket. Is it possible to do this including the changesets or do I have to manually copy the directory to the new repository and commit it there (and lose the version history on the way)?

Comment: +1. Good point. I would just advise you to change the title of the question. You don't really want a partial push (that sounds like a selective commit). You want to "extract" a sub-repository in Mercurial (or something like that...).

Comment: if you want to do selective commits then you definitely want to make it a subrepo as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you want to use the [convert extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Mercurial) to do this. it may be worth while reorganising your main repo to make this a [subrepo](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/subrepos) while you are at it.

Comment: See also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843479/create-a-new-repo-from-sub-folder-in-mercurial-repo-using-convert