# Create a new repo from sub folder in Mercurial Repo using convert

Tags: mercurial, repository, extract, subdirectory

I am trying to extract a folder (call it **Project1**) from an existing Mercurial Repo (call in **MainRepo**) using the Convert extension for Mercurial to Mercurial conversion. I have followed the methods described by Mercurial developers (and elsewhere on the web) under Windows XP:

```
 C:\MainRepo>echo include Project1 > ~myfilemap
 C:\MainRepo>echo rename Project1 . >> ~myfilemap
 C:\MainRepo>hg convert --filemap ~myfilemap . C:\Project1Repo
 C:\MainRepo>cd \Project1Repo
 C:\Project1Repo>hg update
```

This creates the new repo (Project1Repo) with the Mercurial folder/files in place. 
But it does not:

1) Carry across the History relating to the changes made for the Project in folder Project1. (Only the very first history entry for MainRepo and a Convert item are present).

2) Copy across all the source code files from the MainRepo\Project1 to Project1Repo.

I have seen the other similar questions and answers in stackoverflow but these do not appear to help (I have followed methods discussed in them):
[Can I clone part of a Mercurial repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745000/can-i-clone-part-of-a-mercurial-repository)

So the question is: How do I extract a sub-folder from MainRepo with only the sub folder history intact and complete to a new Repo and transfer the source files at the same time?  (though I guess a straight copy will do the last). It's keeping the history that is important - In this case I can make this after a date or Changeset number.

Any help much appreciated as I'm relatively new to this

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The workflow you listed is correct.  That is the way the `convert` extension is intended to work.

Your question states that the repo output by `hg convert` is actually empty (except for "*the very first history entry for MainRepo and a Convert item*").  This would indicate that `convert` was not able to find the path specified in your filemap.

Are you certain that the path given your `include` statement is correct?

The directory name given in your `include` statement must be the full path from your repository root.  For example, your include statement:

```
include Project1
```

requires that the path to Project1 actually be:

```
C:\MainRepo\Project1
```

If `Project1` is actually located somewhere else in `MainRepo`, you will end up with an empty repo after the conversion.

Comment: Hi Tim - Thanks for your reply on this. Yes, it was a path problem. After reading a few more posts on the subject and clearly noting what I needed to do it worked fine. Though after the **hg update** no source files had actually been copied across (that I did manually). A powerful command but not well documented, I feel.